# How can I keep the timer running when I navigate to different fragment with bottom navigation in my android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, kotlin-android-extensions

The fragment gets destroyed and the timer resets to 00:00 when I navigate using bottom navigation.
I have used Chronometer.
I tried *retainInstance=true* but it only helps when screen is rotated.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navHostFragment =supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController =navHostFragment.findNavController()

        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)

    }

}
```

**TimerFragment.kt**

```
class TimerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_timer) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       
          //code
        
    }

     //Few functions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ViewModel approach,
i.e
`ActivityViewModel` and
`FragmentViewModel`

Hold the timer value in your `FragmentViewModel` and when `fragment` is about to be destroyed update the timer value in `ActivityViewModel` in the Activity.

Similarly, in `onCreate()` of `fragment` update the timer value in `FragmentViewModel` from `ActivityViewModel`

The reason is that `ViewModel`'s preserve data after activity recreation.